# Percent data below cutoff value

Tags: r, percentage

I want to calculate the percent of my data below a cutoff value. For example, in the following data, I would like to calculate the percentage of 'measurements' less than or equal to 13.

```
id <- c(3,3,6,6,4,4,3,3)
measurement <- c(10, 13, 14,13, 12, 11, 14, 17)
myData <- data.frame(id, measurement)
myData
```

Comment: Could you please add what has failed? Your data is also incomplete date_cat not found.

Comment: Edited myData. I am very new to R and not able to code for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
id <- c(3,3,6,6,4,4,3,3)
measurement <- c(10, 13, 14,13, 12, 11, 14, 17)
myData <- data.frame(id, measurement)
myData
mean(myData$measurement<=13)
```

Output:

```
[1] 0.625
```